# Copy data to struct in a serial way in C++

Tags: c++, struct, unions

I have a packed struct like this one below

```
struct MyStruct
{
    uint8_t a;
    uint32_t b;
    uint16_t c;
    uint8_t d[4];
    uint16_t e[2];
    uint32_t crc_field;
} __attribute__((packed));
```

I want to store data to it in a serial way, meaning that I want to use `memcpy` or `for` loop to copy data from an array into this struct above.

Consider the example:

```
uint8_t Buffer[64]; //We assume it contains some data.
MyStruct foo; 
memcpy(&foo, Buffer, sizeof(MyStruct));
```

Assuming that I always check the `crc_field` and the data into the `Buffer` was stored in the opposite way (from another `MyStruct` earlier, to `Buffer`). Would there be any issue with this approach?

Would it be better to use a union instead?

```
union MyUnion
{
    uint8_t raw_data[19];
    struct MyStruct
    {
        uint8_t a;
        uint32_t b;
        uint16_t c;
        uint8_t d[4];
        uint16_t e[2];
        uint32_t crc_field;
    } __attribute__((packed));
}

uint8_t Buffer[64]; //We assume it contains some data.
MyUnion foo; 
memcpy(foo.raw_data, Buffer, sizeof(MyStruct));
```

Comment: __attribute__ is not standard C++. A union will not help you being more portable. I would avoid evaluating the struct length myself.

Comment: No, `union` is not better in any way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `MyStruct` class is [trivially copyable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/classes#Trivially_copyable_class). It means that you can safely copy its byte representation in a buffer, and when you will copy back that representation into a `MyStruct` object, that object will take the original value. No need for an union here.

Simply, as the representation of scalar type is not defined in the standard, using that to exchange data between different systems or application compiled with different options could invoke Undefined Behaviour. It may not be a concern, if your compiler documents the standard type and struct representations (probable as you are using the non standard `__attribute__((packed))`). Simply it is restricted to **one** environment and is no longer a portable C++ program...